# I am trying to create multiple UIView without for loop how to do it programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying this for creating multiple `UIView` without for loop
Code:

```
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 40)];
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 40)];
view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 40)];
```

Comment: AAAAAAnnnnndddd, what's the question?

Comment: how to store multiple UIView object into this[self.view addSubview:view,view,view]. is wrong

Comment: Just do it 3 times. Like `view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 40)];
    [self.view addSubview:view];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example to create a `UIView` programmatically

```
UIView *popup=[[UIView alloc]init];
popup.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/3);
popup.center = self.view.center;
popup.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:popup];
```

You can change X,Y,Width,Height as per you requirement.

Comment: Thank you....... but i want to create multiple UIView object and store into [self.view addSubview:"UIView objects ","UIView Second_object"]

Comment: @VijendraYadav you can upvote my answer if it helps you :)